# Primavera P6 - Where Project Start/Finish dates are stored

Tags: primavera

Does anyone know where Primavera P6 stores the project start dates and the project finish dates in the database?

I tried to find this information in different tables, including but not limited to, Project, Task, ProjWBS, but it is not there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a question for the vendor, not the SO forum. It certainly isn't a sql-server or oracle question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look in the TASK table for target_end_date / target_start_date. Here's documentation on the P6 db schema (for v8).https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20686_01/helpmain.htm?toc.htm?schema_documentation.htm